# Get last row of a range in bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I would like to get the last row of a range in Bigtable. Example:

```
key:
prefix:00000001
prefix:00000002
prefix:00000003
```

What would be the best way to get prefix:00000003? Thanks for your help

Comment: As you can see in the Read row with prefix documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples/bigtable-reads-prefix , there are different programming languages to get what you are looking for.

Can you specify what language you are going to use?

Comment: Prefix would five me all the rows, not the last one only right?

Comment: Yes, you’re right. If you want to use Prefix, that would be the result.

Answer (score 0):

could you make it such that the rows are sorted in reverse order e.g. instead of prefix:00000001 make it

```
99999999 - 00000001 = prefix:99999998
99999999 - 00000002 = prefix:99999997
99999999 - 00000003 = prefix:99999996
```

which would sort it in reverse order, then you can simply read the first item.